# Neighbour cell info

Tags: android

I am working on a netmonitoring app for Android and i see that we can information about the serving  cell and neighbouring cells with android.telephony.

I see that it is possible for GSM to get information like MCC MNC CID with this API. But looking at ETSI Technical Specification for GSM network, I don't see those informations being broadcasted in Layer 3 messages. So I'm wondering does anyone know how Android is getting these IDs in this API. Do they get them from some DataBase or directly from the BTS messages?

Thanks